# Apache URL Rewriting - change globally the root of a site

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to internally redirect any URL coming to the root and all the subdirectories of a site to a specific subdirectory (and its subdirectories) of this root, i.e.

http://example.net/index.html --> /prod/index.html
http://example.net/image/im01.jpg --> /prod/image/im01.jpg
     ....

My provider only gives me access to .htaccess, not any global server configuration files.

I tried the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /prod/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work because of the internal redirect and the recursive match of the rule.

Comment: Would this only be in effect if the direct link does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra condition to avoid the infinite loop. Add this RewriteCond before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prod/
```

Some helpful links for Apache URL rewriting:

- [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
- [Apache Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)
- [RewriteRule Tester](http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/)

Comment: I tried it, works fine. The links are very helful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, glad I could help! Maybe you could mark the answer as ACCEPTED?